# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10e59f3c0) to 'NSString' (0x10dba7ad8) swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3

I've been tying to figure out this one for a few days now... Here is my original code:

```
if let ratingDic = dictionary["rating"] as? [String: Any],
        let ratingId = ratingDic["id"] {
        searchResult.ratingID = ratingId as! String
    }
```

Here is my api:

```
"amount" = "50.00";
"rating" =     {
    "name" = "Platinum";
    "id" = 5
```

I'm pretty sure I need to use "valueForKey" so here is my updated code:

```
if let ratingDic = dictionary["rating"] as? [String: Any],
        //let ratingId = ratingDic["id"] {
        let ratingId = [ratingDic.valueForKey("id")!] {
        searchResult.ratingID = ratingId as! Number
    }
```

However now I receive the "Value for type String:Any has no member "valueForKey"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I was forgetting to change the actual variable to a "Double" or number

```
var ratingID = 0.0
```

instead of

```
var ratingID = ""
```

and the code now reads

```
if let ratingDic = dictionary["rating"] as? [String: Any],
        let ratingId = ratingDic["id"] {
        searchResult.ratingID = ratingId as! Double
    }
```

Comment: why not `if let ratingDic = dictionary["rating"] as? [String: Any], let ratingId = ratingDic["id"] as? Double {`